# Generate 3D model of a building with kinect sensor?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, 3d-model, kinect.toolbox, kinect-interaction

I want to generate a 3D model as I walk alone in a building or in a room with the kinect sensor. I want know is this possible?

my idea is to get 3d imaging from interval(like 1 image per 3 meters) and combine them, but how can I do that, how can I match and stitch these models into one 3d model, like in the picture below.

[image]

this image is taken from [here](http://hackaday.com/2013/06/08/3d-mapping-of-rooms-again/)

[kintinuous 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3yYjaLmiqU)

according to this it is possible. Is there any codes (like C#) I can refer?

EDIT: [mapping real world object using kinect](http://blog.decoratorpattern.com/2011/01/23/real-world-mapping-with-the-kinect/)
I found this, and he managed to map real world 3D environment with gps location.for my project im planning to use sensor in a remote controlled car however gps won't work indoors, how can manage this problem?

Comment: http://reconstructme.net/reconstructme-2-0-released/

Comment: Do you mean like Google Maps street view where images are stiched together? But obviously, this is in a smaller scale although the concept is essentially the same.

Comment: yes but i want to genarate 3d model (like to view and observe in blender) google maps not using 3d models i think.

Comment: A good starting point would be to look at Parallel tracking and mapping (PTAM) http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gk/PTAM/